# Google map lagging when zooming or moving

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

So I am using custom marker "IconView" to show my markers and it case the map to lagging "not scrolling smoothly" so much when I move or ty to zoom in or out is there I way to fix this issue and I am only showing 12 markers on the map

Comment: Hi, plz show the way of reproduction.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but on a website, not mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what was the issue if I provide a custom marker IOS keeps re-rendering which case this lagging so setting tracksViewChanges prop to false solve  that issue